# How to serialize key value pairs to a json array in scala?

Tags: json, scala, serialization

Let's say I have multiple key value pairs. The number of key value pairs and their contents can change every run. For example:

```
"favorite_food": "pizza"
"hobby": "running"
```

I want to convert these into json of the following format:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "fun facts" : [
        "favorite_food": "pizza",
        "hobby": "running"
    ]
}
```

Notice the key value pairs are surrounded by square brackets. I am trying to set up some structure of objects so it serializes to this format. I have tried

```
import net.liftweb.json._
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class Person(name: String, fun_facts: Map[String, String])

var john = Person("John Doe", Map("favorite_food" -> "pizza", "hobby" -> "running"))

val json = Serialization.write(john)
```

The problem with this is that rather than using square brackets around the fun facts, it uses curly braces. I.e. `fun_facts: { ... }`.

A potential solution is to define Person as `Person(name: String, fun_facts: String)`. Then, I first serialize my Map of key value pairs, use `serializedMap.replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]")` to convert the curly braces to square brackets, and save that String in my Person object which will be serialized. However, this requires us to lose the object format of the key value pairs which might cause problems if we want to use them before we're ready to return our json string.

Is there a better way to do this? How should I define my Person object so it serializes to the format I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not allowed by [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) to serialize key-value pairs to JSON arrays you can archive that with [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) using a custom codec for `Map[String, String]`.

1. Add dependencies to your build:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core"   % "2.6.0",
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "2.6.0" % "provided" // it is required only in compile-time
)
```

2. Import `core` and `macros` modules:

```scala
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._
```

3. Augment your data structures by required annotations (here `@named` is used to alter a key of the `fun_facts` field):

```scala
case class Person(name: String, @named("fun facts") fun_facts: Map[String, String])
```

4. Create a custom codec for `Map` and derive a codec for `Person`:

```
implicit val mapCodec: JsonValueCodec[Map[String, String]] = new JsonValueCodec[Map[String, String]] {
  override def decodeValue(in: JsonReader, default: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] =
    if (in.isNextToken('[')) {
      if (in.isNextToken(']')) default
      else {
        in.rollbackToken()
        val mb = Map.newBuilder[String, String]
        var i = 0
        while ({
          mb += ((in.readKeyAsString(), in.readString(null)))
          i += 1
          if (i > 100000) { // a safe limit to avoid DoS attacks, see https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11203
            in.decodeError("too many map inserts")
          }
          in.isNextToken(',')
        }) ()
        if (in.isCurrentToken(']')) mb.result()
        else in.arrayEndOrCommaError()
      }
    } else in.readNullOrTokenError(default, '[')

  override def encodeValue(kvs: Map[String, String], out: JsonWriter): Unit = {
    out.writeArrayStart()
    kvs.foreach { case (k, v) =>
      out.writeKey(k)
      out.writeVal(v)
    }
    out.writeArrayEnd()
  }

  override val nullValue: Map[String, String] = null
}

implicit val personCodec: JsonValueCodec[Person] = JsonCodecMaker.make
```

5. Parse and serialize using them:

```scala
val json = """{
             |    "name": "John Doe",
             |    "fun facts" : [
             |        "favorite_food": "pizza",
             |        "hobby": "running"
             |    ]
             |}""".stripMargin.getBytes("UTF-8")
val person = readFromArray[Person](json)
println(person)
println()
println(new String(writeToArray(person, config = WriterConfig.withIndentionStep(4)), "UTF-8"))
```

Expected output:

```
Person(John Doe,Map(favorite_food -> pizza, hobby -> running))

{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "fun facts": [
        "favorite_food": "pizza",
        "hobby": "running"
    ]
}
```